# How to avoid multiple check flag Same table Tsql

Tags: performance, t-sql

Here the code check set flag same table is there any way to avoid this and any simply query avail Kindly advice

```
IF  @Client_Type ='R'       
BEGIN      
SELECT @Auth_t=1  FROM GM_RETAILER WHERE  Retailerid =@Client_id      
    
SELECT @Auth=1  FROM GM_RETAILER WHERE isnull(First_trans_Date,'')= ''   and Retailerid =@Client_id   
            
END
```

Comment: combine into single query and use `CASE` expression to check for `First_trans_Date` and assign to `@Auth` accordingly

Comment: like this query    SELECT @Auth_t=1 ,@Auth=CASE WHEN isnull(First_trans_Date,'')= '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  FROM GM_RETAILER WHERE  Retailerid =@Client_id

Comment: test it out to confirm that it works for you